# Understanding Assembly basic code

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

```
pointr: .word pointr
mov #pointr,r0
mov pointr,r1
```

Can someone please explain the difference between the values r0 and r1?

Comment: From experience with asm syntax for other machines, likely `#pointr` is an immediate operand (the address of the label), while `pointr` is a memory source operand, so the 2nd `mov` is a load instruction.

Comment: `pointr: .word pointr` creates a label for a word value containing the actual absolute address of `pointr`. `mov #pointr,r0` uses immediate mode to move the value of the `pointr` label directly to r0. `mov pointr,r1` uses relative mode to move the word value at `pointr` into `r1`. Since the word value stored at `pointr` is the address of `pointr` itself  it has the effect of moving the address of `pointr` to r1. The values in r0 and r1 should be the same.

Comment: what assembler are you using, syntax is determined by assembler, and with the port of pdp-11 to gnu the gnu assembler syntax is very much not compatible with DEC pdp-11 assembler (documentation).  I assume this is gnu assembler?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - r0 and r1 will hold the same value, but just because of the initialization in the first line

Let's break this down, instruction by instruction:

```
pointr: .word pointr
```

This means "define a label named 'pointer' in address X, and put the value of the label (in this case, X) in that address". So in address X there's a word holding the value X.

```
mov #pointr,r0
```

This means "move the value of label 'pointr' (in this case, the address X) to r0". So r0 will hold the value X because 'pointr' is the label for this address.

```
mov pointr,r1
```

This means "move the value that sits in the address of label 'pointr' (in this case, also X) to r1". So r1 will hold the value X because of the ".word pointr" part of the first line in code.

To clarify, if we were to replace the first line of code to get:

`pointr: .word pointr+2
mov #pointr,r0
mov pointr,r1`

the value of r0 will not change (in comparison to the original code), but the value of r1 will.